# Passing the control type via SetValue

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I pass a UIElement as Control and then call SetValue, I want to know how I can pass the first parameter as the control type from the UIElement rather than hard coding as shown below as ListBox

```
Control As UIElement
Control.SetValue(ListBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, ControlBinding.DataFieldName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of ListBox use ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPathProperty